# is it possible to install libBLT.2.4.so.8.5?

Tags: ubuntu

my tkinter is linked to libBLT.2.4.so.8.5 and libtk8.5. However, my ubuntu system only has libBLT.2.4.so.8.6. Is it possible to install libBLT.2.4.so.8.5?

Comment: Why not just install `python-tk` and use the `tkinter` there?

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks! I do not know if this going to cause more trouble or not. We had a locally installed python with different version and patch than the system one.